# "Connection was reset" while uploading files bigger than 25MB

Tags: php, html, apache, file-upload

I have a website running on a Linux server

> Linux web3 4.19.27-gentoo-r1 
>   x86_64
>
> Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) PHP/5.6.40 mpm-itk/2.4.7-04 OpenSSL/1.0.2r

I have an upload page setup and I can upload files with less than 25MB, but when I upload files bigger than 25MB I get the error "Connection was reset"

I have access to the php.ini and .htaccess files and I have set the below settings, but the issue still persists:

> ini_get('upload_max_filesize'): 100M
>
> ini_get('post_max_size'): 100M
>
> ini_get('max_input_time'): 900
>
> ini_get('max_execution_time'): 900
>
> ini_get('memory_limit'): 512M
>
> ini_get('log_errors'): 1
>
> ini_get('file_uploads'): 1

-

> LimitRequestBody 102400000

Are there any other settings that could affect the upload?

Edit 1: Could this be due to a limitation on the temp folder from the server ?
Because such a limit of 25MB seems quite strange. If so, how can I check the limit?

Edit 2: I contacted our IT support, who are hosting the web server and they simply said that it works on their side using the exact same php upload code :/
How can it work on their side but not on my computer and the computers of my colleagues which are located in a different country?

Edit 3: After investigating for more than 2 hours, our IT support said there is no solution for this.

Comment: apache timeout settings? also change max_execution_time to 0 (unlimited)

Answer (score 0):

Use any one of these solution, I hope your problem will be resolved.

**Solution 1: PHP File**

```
// It will work in specific file only    
set_time_limit(0); // Put this code in the beginning of the file
```

**Solution 2: php.ini**

```
// It will apply globally
max_execution_time = 0
```

Comment: Nothing so far even suggests that a PHP script execution(!) timeout is the problem here. You should not post a pure guess as an answer.